# Where is the source for R.layout.date_picker_dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-source

Referring to the docs at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html. I am trying to merge DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog into one. But when I simply do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/date_time_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_time_display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_bright" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#DDDDDD" />

    <DatePickerDialog
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
         />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#DDDDDD" />

    <TimePickerDialog
        android:id="@+id/time_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

when I try to extract the view using

```
DatePickerDialog dateDialog = (DatePickerDialog) view.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
```

I get the error message that I cannot cast from view to DatePickerDialog. So I open the source of DatePickerDialog to see how to create my own. But I can't find the source for R.layout.date_picker_dialog. Does anyone know how to open that xml file?

Answer (score 1):

All Android framework resources in the sources of Android are located in the `frameworks/base/core/res` folder.

Answering your question, the xml file of DatePicker can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_dialog.xml): `frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_dialog.xml`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question but to your problem: You should not be composing `DatePickerDialog` or `TimePickerDialog` in your layout. Instead, use `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` components, without the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it locates in:

```
adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platforms/android-19/data/res/layout/date_picker_dialog.xml
```

Hope this help!